# Using Jquery how to add background color of first child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have `li` elements as shown below. I want to provide background color to the first `li` within the main `li` tags,

For example consider the `li` with `id="mli1970"`, Now I want to color the first `li` within this element.

```html
<ul class="chlk-timeline-years" id="chlk-timeline-decades">
  <li data-group-id="e4b5b419-9bf2-42dd-ecf5-6750ae5c0365" id="mli1837">1837
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-group-id="7ead4d3a-a020-4e87-c5ca-f8043047c954" id="mli1970">1970
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="ffabab46-df77-40af-fe86-710284837703" id="mli1945">1945
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="85bdb673-6287-48fd-808c-9aa64accc12e" id="mli1978">1978
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: you have the id you can add style to it

Comment: `mli1970` - 2nd child

Comment: Why did u degrade it ?

Comment: Without id i want to add the color

Comment: @guradio if u don't know the answer Don't try to degrade

Comment: @Rijo FYI its not my downvote. also this one deserves its downvote you didnt even bother to put effort in solving this problem you can solve this by looking for solution and the solution is not make SO people do your homework for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Jquery Solution**

To get hold of first child use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector and specify the index of the child, starting from 0.

```
$('#mli1970 li:eq(0)') // this selects the first 'li' inside your `li` with id mli1970
```

```js
$('#mli1970 li:eq(0)').css('background-color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chlk-timeline-years" id="chlk-timeline-decades">
  <li data-group-id="e4b5b419-9bf2-42dd-ecf5-6750ae5c0365" id="mli1837">1837
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-group-id="7ead4d3a-a020-4e87-c5ca-f8043047c954" id="mli1970">1970
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="ffabab46-df77-40af-fe86-710284837703" id="mli1945">1945
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="85bdb673-6287-48fd-808c-9aa64accc12e" id="mli1978">1978
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Also as a **CSS** Solution you can do the following

- `#mli1970 li:first-child`
- `#mli1970 li:first-of-type`
- `#mli1970 li:nth-child(0)`
- `#mli1970 li:nth-of-type(0)`

Ofcourse the same selectors can be used in `Jquery` selectors as well.

Comment: Can u please upgrade my question. Because I'm try to learn jquery

Comment: After 4 minutes need to accept

Comment: @Rijo I will update.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work and commitment

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(".chlk-timeline-years > li:first-child").css('background-color', '#F00');
```

or

```
$(".chlk-timeline-years > li:first-child ul li:first-child").css('background-color', '#F00');
```

Comment: Thank you so  much

Comment: Sure. No problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('#mli1970 li:first-child').css('background-color','blue');
```

See The Snippest :

```js
$('#mli1970 li:first-child').css('background-color','cyan');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chlk-timeline-years" id="chlk-timeline-decades">
  <li data-group-id="e4b5b419-9bf2-42dd-ecf5-6750ae5c0365" id="mli1837">1837
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-group-id="7ead4d3a-a020-4e87-c5ca-f8043047c954" id="mli1970">1970
    <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="ffabab46-df77-40af-fe86-710284837703" id="mli1945">1945
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="85bdb673-6287-48fd-808c-9aa64accc12e" id="mli1978">1978
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you fro your hard work and commitment

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mli1970 li').css({
  background: 'red'
});
```

Resources:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/css/
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Answer (score 0):

As explained in https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/:

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css('background-color', '#F00');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution, Each first occurred li under main li will be colored red**

```js
 $('.chlk-timeline-years li[data-action="data-color"]').each(function () {
 $(this).find('li').eq(0).css("background-color","red");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chlk-timeline-years" id="chlk-timeline-decades">
  <li data-group-id="e4b5b419-9bf2-42dd-ecf5-6750ae5c0365" data-action="data-color" id="mli1837">1837
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-group-id="7ead4d3a-a020-4e87-c5ca-f8043047c954" data-action="data-color" id="mli1970">1970
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="ffabab46-df77-40af-fe86-710284837703" data-action="data-color" id="mli1945">1945
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-group-id="85bdb673-6287-48fd-808c-9aa64accc12e" data-action="data-color" id="mli1978">1978
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```